# Cocoa maximized event for resizing content

Tags: ios, cocoa, resize, zooming, nswindow

I have an `NSWindow` and have implemented `windowWillResize`.

In this method, I have some code that resize my window's content. It works great.

But when the user wants to maximize (zoom) the window with green plus button (in the title bar), the window is growing but `windowWillResize` is not called.

I have tried to implement `windowShouldZoom` method. The method is called but I cannot fetch the window size at this time.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Notifications like `windowWillResize:toSize:` are really more for constraining the window, e.g. for image viewers that might want to align the window on certain boundaries.  It is possible for the frame to change without invoking notifications at all (`setFrame:display:`, for instance) so it's not good to rely on such callbacks to do layout.

Consider making an `NSView` subclass that is the parent of the views you want to arrange, and then implement methods such as `resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:` at the *view* level.  This also has the advantage that you can keep the layout logic contained in a subtree: maybe one day you decide that the views are not necessarily required to use the whole window (e.g. user-controlled show/hide of a sidebar), and this way the "main" window region can magically use whatever space it is given to do its layout.

Note that using `NSView` as the basis for resize does not mean the window state is unavailable; for instance a view can detect if the window has begun or ended a "live resize" and optimize layout accordingly.